# How to omit one property from interface, but not with type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, types

I need to make one interface that extends from 2 another, but I get the error: 
**Interface 'IModalProps' cannot simultaneously extend types 'ModalProps' and 'ModalRNProps'.   Named property 'onShow' of types 'ModalProps' and 'ModalRNProps' are not identical.**:

```
export interface IModalProps extends ModalProps, ModalRNProps {
  showCloseButton?: boolean;
  showDoneBar?: boolean;
}
```

I can do omit only with type like this:

```
type OmitA = Omit<ModalProps, "onShow">;
```

But I can not after make extends with type, because it is possible only with interfaces. Can you tell me please how can I omit one property from the interface and after create one extendable interface from a few interfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try interfaces instead of types

```js
export interface IModalProps {
  showCloseButton?: boolean;
  showDoneBar?: boolean;
}


export interface Test extends Omit<IModalProps, 'showDoneBar'> {

}

const test: Test = {
    showCloseButton: true,
    showDoneBar: false, // fails
 };
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFkIATTAGwAUoIwBnOAbwCg446ALCAdwGFyIdYACEArjBgQkAfgBccAEYQI5YJiQBuVuy7cAIlJGYocxctXqtAX2a3QkWIhRosuOABVgdeKFRISDADyALYIMAA8RKQU1LR0ADRwAOScPAZIRlBJAHxMtjbM2FLecKje8p4lALx5bGypfAJCYhJS8jBQosDx2vW66ZnyWORCPXBWGkA)

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much, I did not it is possible to do with interfaces)))

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to mark it as the right answer if it worked for you :)